# How to insert 2chars before words

Tags: c, string

So I'm trying to make a game for school but I can't make it working. 
One of the elements should be that the output string has the characters 'ay' in front of every consonant. 
The code that I'm using right now is pretty close I think but I don't know anymore. I should be able to input any random string and convert it to a string with ay in front of every word starting with a consonant.
An example when I put in the string : "I like writing C code"
the output should become: "I aylike aywriting ayC aycode"

```
char insertChar(char str[])
{
    int k;
    k = 0;


    for ( str[k] != '\0'; k < strlen(str); k++)
    {
        if(str[k] = ' ' && str[k] != 'a' || str[k] != 'e' || str[k] != 'i' || str[k] != 'o' || str[k] != 'u' || str[k] != 'A' || str[k] != 'E' || str[k] != 'I' || str[k] != 'O' || str[k] != 'U')
        {
            putchar('a');
            putchar('y');
        }
        else
        {
            putchar(str[k]);
        }
        k++;
    }
}



void main(void)
{
    printf("** Welcome to the Double Dutch game **\n");
    printf("Please enter a string: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", myString);
    insertChar(myString);
    printf("Double Dutch translation: ");

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: About the `if` condition: please note that `=` is an assignment operator in C, not a comparison operator.

Comment: Please provide example input output and clearly state was is wrong with the code in its current state

Comment: First two things that any C class should teach you: 1. compile with all warnings enabled 2. do not ignore warnings.

Comment: `for ( str[k] != '\0'; k < strlen(str); k++)` First part of `for` is initialisation, SECOND is continuation condition. So first part is wrong (and probably duplicates similar condition, eos)

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s", myString);` is a problem in many ways.  No input limit, unneeded `s`, following UB when line begins with `\n`, `\n` always left in `stdin`, `myString` not defined.

Comment: @Jurjen Kuijstermans  It is unclear whether you need just output the source string in the given format or build a new string that contains the prefix.

Answer (score 1):

You need use an `or` operator instead of `and`. Also, you are incorrectly incrementing `k` twice. See the following working snippet:

```
for ( ; k < strlen(str); k++)
{
if(str[k] != 'a' && str[k] != 'e' && str[k] != 'i' && str[k] != 'o' && str[k] != 'u' && str[k] != 'A' && str[k] != 'E' && str[k] != 'I' && str[k] != 'O' && str[k] != 'U')
 {
     putchar('a');
     putchar('y');
     putchar(str[k]);
 }
  else
  {
      putchar(str[k]);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: @JurjenKuijstermans, no it works as expected. I just ran it myself and it produced the desired output.

Comment: Replace`str[k] != '\0'` in the `for` statement with `k=0`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, yeah, `str[k] != '\0'` is not needed since the OP is already initializing k to 0 before the loop. But my code only fixes the logical error.

Comment: Yes, even better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following is a correct version:

```
void *insertChar(char *str)
{
  int i= 0;

  while (str[i])
  {
    putchar(str[i]);
    if (str[i] == ' ' && !strchr("AEIOUYaeiouy", str[i+1]))
    {
        putchar('a');
        putchar('y'); 
    }
    i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't trust yourself.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, right... more bugs. Had to add a `!`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach by tokenizing words. Working example - https://ideone.com/GKwEL5

```
void insertChar(char str[])
{
  int space = 0;

  char *word;
  word = strtok (str, " ");

  while ( word != NULL )
  {
    if( space )
      putchar(' ');
    space = 1;

    if( !strchr("aeiouAEIOU", word[0]) )
    {
      putchar('a');
      putchar('y');
    }

    printf ("%s", word);

    word = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to build a new string using the prefix from the source string. In this case you have to allocate dynamically a new character array within the function.

If so then the function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

char * double_dutch_translation( const char *s )
{
    const char *vowels = "AEIOUaeiou";
    const char *prefix= "ay";

    size_t n = 0;
    size_t len = 0;

    for ( ; s[len] != '\0'; len++ )
    {
        if ( strchr( vowels, s[len] ) == NULL && 
             ( len == 0 || isblank( ( unsigned char )s[len-1] ) ) )
        {
            ++n;
        }
    }

    char *result = malloc( len + 1 + 2 * n );

    if ( result != NULL )
    {
        size_t i = 0, j = 0;

        do
        {
            if ( strchr( vowels, s[i] ) == NULL && 
                ( i == 0 || isblank( ( unsigned char )s[i-1] ) ) )
            {
                result[j++] = prefix[0];
                result[j++] = prefix[1];
            }

            result[j++] = s[i];
        } while ( s[i++] != '\0' );
    }

    return result;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s1[] = "I like writing C code";
    char s2[] = "He doesn't like writing C code";

    char *p = double_dutch_translation( s1 );

    if ( p )
    {
        printf( "\"%s\"\n", s1 );
        printf( "Double Dutch translation: \"%s\"\n", p );
        free( p );
    }

    p = double_dutch_translation( s2 );

    if ( p )
    {
        printf( "\"%s\"\n", s2 );
        printf( "Double Dutch translation: \"%s\"\n", p );
        free( p );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
"I like writing C code"
Double Dutch translation: "I aylike aywriting ayC aycode"
"He doesn't like writing C code"
Double Dutch translation: "ayHe aydoesn't aylike aywriting ayC aycode"
```

Pay attention to the string `s2` that starts with the letter 'H' that is not preceded with a blank.